# Python : Compare two folders and move files with the same name from 1 folder to another

Tags: python

I have two folders in windows. Both these have files with the same name but with different extension. I'm trying to compare these two folders, and if they have files with the same names I need to copy them from 1 folder to another.

I have done this using batch programs, but I want to do this guys using Python.
I searched here and got some bits and pieces, however I'm not sure if I'm right? 
Can you guys please help me out?

```
exm1=[os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in os.listdir(r'\Path') if os.path.splitext(x)[1]=='.trn']
exm2=[os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in os.listdir(r'\Path') if os.path.splitext(x)[1]=='.trn']
```

Comment: Are the extensions always going to be the same? Say `.ext1` in one place and `.ext2` in the other?

Comment: Yes, the extensions are always the same.

Comment: I just saw the shutil module, will that be helpful?

Comment: It will be, I used it below.

Comment: Thank you! I have a few more modifications, I'll see if this does the job.

Answer (score 2):

You are going about it just about right for for listing just the base names without the extensions. What you are missing is detecting what is missing.

If you can easily reconstruct the filenames in directory 1; because they have all the same extension, for example; then I'd use *[sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)* here; sets make listing the difference between the two directories easy:

```
import os.path
import shutil

source = r'\Path1'
dest = r'\Path2'

sourcefiles = {os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in os.listdir(source) if os.path.splitext(x)[1] == '.ext1'}
destfiles = {os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in os.listdir(source) if os.path.splitext(x)[1] == '.ext2'}

for missing in sourcefiles - destfiles:   # calculate the difference
    sourcefile = os.path.join(source, missing + '.ext1')
    destfile = os.path.join(dest, missing + '.ext2')
    shutil.copy(sourcefile, destfile)
```

Comment: Hello! This works good, Thank you. But shutil is replacing the file irrespective of the extension. The file is copied to the destination, but I don't want the file to be replaced. I want both the files to exist in the destination folder. For example test.ext1 and test.ext2 both should be present in the dest. I would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: @AniShetty: So you want to copy `file.ext1` to `dest` only if `file.ext2` exists there? You need to be *clear* in your copy rules.

Comment: It could be enough to just copy to `missing + '.ext1'` then?

Comment: No, but I changed the destfile also to have .ext1. It works good! Thank you

Comment: Now in this script the destination is defined to a single folder. What if I have multiple destination folders, and I have to compare 1 source folder with multiple destination folders, which performs the same function?

Comment: @AniShetty: You can loop over those folders and determine the intersection for each, sure.

Answer (score 0):

This will copy all files that are not in folder 1 to 2 and vice versa

```
import os
import shutil

folder1 = "C:\\path\\folder\\1\\"
folder2 = "C:\\path\\folder\\2\\"
data_folder1 = [(x[0], x[2]) for x in os.walk(folder1)]
data_folder2 = [(x[0], x[2]) for x in os.walk(folder2)]

x=0
for file in data_folder1[0][1]:
    if file not in data_folder2:
        shutil.copy(folder1+data_folder1[0][1][x], folder2+data_folder1[0][1][x])
    x+=1

y=0
for file in data_folder2[0][1]:
    if file not in data_folder1:
        shutil.copy(folder2+data_folder2[0][1][y], folder1+data_folder2[0][1][y])
    y+=1
```